# how to manage jpa bidirectional relation ships correctly?

Tags: jpa, ejb

I am using EJB3.2 and JPA 2.1.
In my application I have these entities (in brief) :

```
@Entity
public class Festival
{
    int Id;
    String name;
    ...
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "merchant", referencedColumnName = "Id")
    Merchant merchant;
}

@Entity
public class Merchant
{
    int Id;
    String name;

    ...

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "category", referencedColumnName = "Id")
    Category category;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "city", referencedColumnName = "Id")
    City city;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "festival")
    List<Festival> festivalList;
}

@Entity
public class Category
{
    int Id;
    String name;
    ...
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "merchant")
    List<Merchant> merchantList;
}

@Entity
public class City
{
    int Id;
    String name;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "merchant")
    List<Merchant> merchantList;
}
```

thus, (Festival, Merchant) has a bidirectional relationship like (Merchant, Category) and (Merchant, City)

the problem is when i remove or change a merchant, still there is an unchanged copy of it in categories merchantList and cities merchantList ! and so on..

how should I manage these changes?! why JPA doesn't do the changes to other copies it self? doesn't it increase the wrong copies risk?!

Comment: You are not letting JPA to know about bidirectional relationship. It can be done by "mappedBy" attribute.  Please read the article: http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/jpa/one-to-many-bidirectional-mapping-in-jpa/

Comment: Dear @Shanu, my problem is not this. i have wrote the code here in brief the real code has that attribute, but for resolution, i will write them here too on edit.

Comment: Yes, Please provide mode code snippet, to provide concrete help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JPA treats your entities like regular java objects and does not maintain relationships for you - the application is responsible for ensuring that both sides of a bidirectional relationship are kept in sync when you change one side.  So when you dereference a City from a Merchant, you must remove the reference to the Merchant from the City's merchantList and then merge if necessary.

Otherwise your view of the data via the java objects will become out of synch with the database until the objects are refreshed from the database.  You can weigh the value and costs of keeping both sides in sync or refreshing when needed or even not mapping the non-owning side and determine what is better for your application on an entity by entity basis.

Comment: is it a good pattern to change my DAO to supervise my CRUD and when an object changes, propagate it to it's references in related entities?
for example when i cal "em.update(merchant)" then it immediately calls merchant.getCity().getMerchantList().find(merchant.getId()) = merchant ?

Comment: @HamidAdldoost You don't have to do that when you simply update some  fields in entity, JPA guarantees that only one instance of an entity with the same ID can exist in the memory (one managed instance, of course). That means if you do, for example, `em.find(MyEntity.class, someId)` multiple times, it will always return the same exact object. You only need to refresh when you change relations between entities.

Answer (score 1):

I think this quote from "Java Persistence With Hibernate" (p. 261) by Christian Bauer and Gavin King may be useful for you :

> Contrary to EJB 2.0 CMR, Hibernate and JPA associations are all
>   inherently unidirectional.

So the association from Merchant to Category is different than association from Category to Merchant, and you need to manage them separately.

edit:
I adjusted your initial bean config to look as it should:
(Of course, you will use an appropriate primary key generation strategy.)

```
@Entity
public class Festival
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    int Id;
    String name;

    @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "merchant")
    Merchant merchant;
}
@Entity
public class Merchant
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    int Id;
    String name;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "category")
    Category category;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "city")
    City city;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "merchant")
    List<Festival> festivalList;
}
@Entity
public class Category
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    int Id;
    String name;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "category")
    List<Merchant> merchantList;
}
@Entity
public class City
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    int Id;
    String name;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "city")
    List<Merchant> merchantList;
}
```

Comment: Does it mean that when I change, add or remove a merchant i should update city.merchantList and category.merchantList by myself? how about when the model is so more complicated?!! isn't it dirty?

Comment: When you change a merchant or add a new one, you need to reload the city (category) list of merchants.

Comment: what do u mean by "reload"? does it mean "em.refresh(city)" ?

Comment: The EntityManager.refresh() will do it.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to persist(merchant) before calling categories.getMerchantList().

Comment: I have done it, but still the previous value of category.getMerchantList() is not updated and i get wrong data when calling it  while merchant itself is ok!